# How to calculate unique combinations using one or more choices, where duplicate elements exist.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My son and I are working through combinations/permutations problems, and I've questioned myself into a corner.
How do I set up a problem to find unique combinations by choosing one or more elements from a set, where the set contains duplicate elements.
For example, how many unique combinations can be made using one or more of the following coins: 2 nickels, 1 dime, and 1 quarter.

Here I have 4 total elements.  If the nickels were not duplicates, then choosing at least one, would be the sum of $ {4\choose 4}$, $ {4\choose 3}$,$ {4\choose 2}$,and $ {4\choose 1}$.
But, when I have a duplicate, it is throwing me for a loop.  $ {4\choose 3}$ not taking into account the duplicate nickels yields 4.  This should be 3 if removing the duplicate nickels - NND, NNQ,and NDQ.  I thought about taking the combinations,and then dividing by the duplicate, i.e. calculating combinations of letters where duplicate letters exist.  I keep getting $ {4\choose 3}$ / 2! (the nickels), and get 2.
Similarly,$ {4\choose 2}$ yields 6 without taking into account the nickels.  Taking the duplicates into account, it should be 4: NN, NQ, ND, QD. I don't know how to set this up though.

In a follow-up step, I'm ultimately trying to figure out something like: What is the total number of unique sums one can create from using one or more of the following coins: 2 nickels, 3 dimes, 6 pennies, and a quarter?  (the similar difficulty of subtracting out the options where combinations of one (or more) coin(s) equal the amount of another)

Comment: Beware! Many problems like this are most efficiently solved by a brute force enumeration of all the outcomes: trying to be clever may take more time than just doing the dumb thing. (And it is good to know how to go about enumerating all the outcomes efficiently.) (Aside: as a technical point, sets in mathematics don't have duplicate elements, the data in your problem is a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).)

Comment: PS. the above comment is directed at your follow-up step, where you want to know how many different sums you can form. If you are just interested in the number of multisets of coins that you can get, the approach of @David's answer is the way to go (and can be combined with brute force to give a reasonably efficient way of enumerating the possible sums).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just choose the nickels, dimes and quarters separately.  You can have $0,1$ or $2$ nickels ($3$ options), $0$ or $1$ dimes ($2$ options), $0$ or $1$ quarters ($2$ options), total $3\times2\times2=12$ options.  However this includes the option of choosing nothing at all, which your problem does not permit, so the final answer is $11$ options.

Comment: Thank you.   I have to sort out my mind to see why this weeds out duplicates, or as Rob correctly pointed out, the multiset.  By choosing the elements separately, the option of 1 nickel eliminates the issue of having a duplicate.  Either nickel would be used in that one choice.  It makes perfect sense and is embarrassingly simple.